# Hide an element inside an <object> tag with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object-tag

I want to hide an element inside an `<object>` tag , the element is `<div class="footer">...</div>` I tried this code but still not working, please help me

```
<div> 
     <object id="t" type="text/html" data="https://www.example.com/" width="100%" height="600px" style="overflow:auto;">
     </object>
</div>
```

and this is my javascript code

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
       var t = document.querySelector("#t");
       var htmlDocument = t.contentDocument;
       htmlDocument.getElementsByClassName("footer")[0].style.visibility='hidden';
  });

</script>
```

Comment: use CSS - eg .footer { display: none}

Comment: I do not see a footer element at all.
https://codepen.io/ajanth2012/pen/MXaPpp

Comment: your div does not have a set footer class at all.
Not sure what you are trying to do with this, but if you just want to hide it, it is easier just to give it a display:none in css, like someone mentioned previously

Comment: object tag is to embed the website : https://www.example.com/ inside my application , so I want to hide the footer of this website : https://www.example.com/

Comment: If that object is loaded from another origin you won't be able to access it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you I fixed it (hide the footer of example.com inside my website) by using an iframe and css following this code :

```
<div style="overflow:hidden;">
<iframe src="https://www.example.com/" name="iframe_all" frameborder="0"  style="width: 100%; height: 650px; margin-bottom: -120px;" ></iframe>
</div>
```